# how to make shapefile in geometry column of ms sql?

Tags: sql-server

I was tried ogr2ogr command like this.

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" "C:\temp\sqlexport.shp" "MSSQL:server=[RemoteServerIp];database=[dbname];User Id=[user];Password=[password];trust_connection=yes;" -sql "SELECT [geometrycolumn].STAsBinary() FROM [tableName] WHERE [indexColumn] = 1;" -overwrite
```

but I saw error message.
Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.

I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: This is an MSQL issue that has nothing to do with the geography, You need to configure MSQL to trust your machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have conflicting login options in your connection string.

There are [two main types of authentication](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144284(v=sql.105).aspx):

1. Windows Authentication - using your (or service account's) Windows Active Directory credentials. This option does **not** require a user ID and password to be specified. This is designated by `trust_connection=yes`
2. SQL Authentication - a login made on SQL Server which would require a user ID and password to be used. This is designated by `User Id=[user];Password=[password]`

So you need to remove the `trusted_connection=yes` if you're using SQL Authentication, or if you want to use Windows credentials then remove the `User Id` and `Password` portion of the connection string and check to make sure the account running this exists has proper permissions [setup in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029014/how-to-add-active-directory-user-group-as-login-in-sql-server) for this domain.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are running your GIS programme from a domain that is not trusted by the domain in which SQL Server resides.

That are numerous methods you can use to correct this. You should discuss with your network admin/sql server admin as to the best approach.

1. Create a SQL Server Account and use those credentials to connect to the SQL Server <-- this might be the easiest
2. Trust the domain in which your GIS Programme is running <--I would be loath to do this